# Pass data to children in IonReactRouter

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic/React App I added this routing system to my page `page.tsx`. In `page.tsx` the app recieves data from the server (via a webSocket-connection). I want to pass that data (or parts of it) on to the the the components. 
I there a way I can add props to the components or another way to pass the data to them?

```
<IonReactRouter>
  <Route path="/Widgets" component={Widgets} exact />
  <Route path="/Settings" component={Settings} exact />
  <Route path="/Checklists" component={Checklists} exact />
</IonReactRouter>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Route
  path='/Checklists'
  render={(props) => < Checklists {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
/>
```

here is some document and videos - https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/

Comment: Saved me twice in two days now! Amazing! Thank you so much!